# identity server 4 handle multiple external authentication methods

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

When regestering multiple external authentication methods with identity server 4 then handler for the login doesnt resolve to the correct handler.

```
var providers =  List<ExternalProvider>()

foreach (var option in providers)
    builder.AddGoogle(option.Name, option.Name, x => x.Bind(option));
```

When the service handels the request it hits the `AuthenticationMiddleware` class in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` that handels the request. The AuthenticationMiddleware gets the list of all registered providers, but the first one is of type Google aswell but not for the one I'm loging in with. When the request goes to the `OAuthHandler` to Unprotect the state, it cant as the google options it is using is diffrent than the one I'm logging in with. (This is not a problem tho) The problem comes in with the `RemoteAuthenticationHandler` that calls the `OAuthHandler`. In the `RemoteAuthenticationHandler` it does

```
var authResult = await HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync();
if (authResult == null)
{
    exception = new InvalidOperationException("Invalid return state, unable to redirect.");
}
```

that causes the error page to be displayed
[image]

I have debuged the code and if you force it to skip the error and contenue to the next auth scheme the request succeeeds.

Now the question:
Is there a way to avoid this error and have multiple external authentication methods of the same type (Google in this case)?

Note: I have diffrent external authentication methods setup that works. Google, Azure Ad, Facebook. This problem is when adding more than one Google authentication method.

I have tried diffrent ways of registering the external authentication methods and I have tried registering them with the same name to allow the unprotecting of the state to pass but no success as you can only have 1 with the same name.

Comment: I was going through the AuthenticationMiddleware again and found this comment on top of the code that calls the "incorrect" google handler

// Give any IAuthenticationRequestHandler schemes a chance to handle the request

From that it seems like the google handler shouldn't through when it cant handle the request

Comment: Found a solution to this problem. When registering your provider, you need to register the provider with a custom callback url. (Setup the google client this the same callback) That solves the problem for this.